# LLVM OpenMP Support

Tags: llvm, openmp

I want to know whether there is any function/method in LLVM to add Open-MP constructs in LLVM IR. Does llvm-3.0 still support OpenMP directives?

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP is a high-level language extension. So, it's C/C++/FORTRAN front-end which should lower the pragma's into necessary runtime calls and code alterations.

I don't see how OpenMP can be "added" to LLVM IR. If you need C/C++/FORTRAN compiler which supports OpenMP pragmas and emit LLVM IR - try dragonegg.

Comment: In recent ml thread [(LLVMdev) OpenMP support for LLVM/jan2012](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-January/046823.html), using of intrinsics proposed. "people interested in automatic parallelization are 
probably more interested in transforming a plain LLVM-IR loop into 
LLVM-IR with OpenMP extensions."

Comment: @osgx: if we're talking about library independent representation of call to omp runtime, then yes, special intrinsics is a natural way. Autopar code also in theory may produce the omp-aware code. So, most probably the original question needs to be clarified how "LLVM can still support OpenMP directives" :)

Comment: Right. Basically what the openmp lowering that happens is a set of library calls for the various openmp directives (as well as some cfg changes), there's nothing specific that's needed in the IR for openmp. 

If you want to be able to notice OpenMP directives and reconstruct at a higher level the loop transforms then you might want some IR support, but I'm not positive that it would be needed.